# ng new not working states the error - Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used

Tags: angular-cli

While trying to create new angular application using Angular CLI 8, it shows the error the same for ng update

I have many time reinstalled angular cli & node.
Also updated the local cli

```
ng new ng8
Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
Error: Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
    at Workspace._assertLoaded (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/workspace/workspace.js:108:19)
    at Workspace._getTool (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/workspace/workspace.js:214:14)
    at Workspace.getCli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/experimental/workspace/workspace.js:196:21)
    at NewCommand.getDefaultSchematicCollection (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:266:36)
    at NewCommand.parseCollectionName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/new-impl.js:41:43)
    at NewCommand.initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/new-impl.js:22:40)
    at NewCommand.validateAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:127:20)
    at async Object.runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:178:24)
    at async default_1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:32:31)
```

Comment: Something to look at: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10757

Comment: Already tried it but no helps

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14591#issuecomment-497505258 helped me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your .angular-config.json, it worked for me.

```
rm ~/.angular-config.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I have came across same issue when I accidentally rewritten `~/.angular-config.json` with empty content.

Deleting this file fixed the issue.